# python match every position for number, space and hypens

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex in python to match a string that contains only numbers[0-9], space and hypens.

```
print re.match('\d*', '1sdsd')
```

The above pattern matches even when it contain characters.

Comment: your regex will match any string. If you want to match a string only containing certain characters, you need to add `^` to the front and `$` to the back of the expression

Comment: read the documentation for the method you are using.

Comment: @MaartenFabré actually, using `match`, you don't need the `^`

Answer (score 2):

Your answer will match because there is a digit in the string. If you want it to match only if all the characters match your regular expression you have to specify the beginning and the end of the string by using `^` and `$`.

```
  print re.match('^[\d\- ]+$', '1sdsd')
```

**Working Sample**

https://regex101.com/r/KAzHMA/1

Comment: Isn't `+` better than `{1,}` ?

Comment: you don't need the `^`, because you are using `match`

Comment: If he doesn't use it it will match because of the one. I believe he only wants it match if the string only has numbers, dashes, or spaces.